# If I assign a new value to JS variable does it break its bindings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a JavaScript variable that stores a websocket connection like so:

```
var ws = $.websocketSettings.factory(url);
        $(ws)
            .bind('open', $.websocketSettings.open)
            .bind('close', $.websocketSettings.close)
            .bind('message', $.websocketSettings.message)
            .bind('error', $.websocketSettings.error)
            .bind('relaySent', $.websocketSettings.relayTimeout)
            .bind('relayRetry', $.websocketSettings.relayRetry)
            .bind('jumpStart', $.websocketSettings.jumpFactory);
```

However in case the connection drops, I have a `jumpStart` event that resets the `ws` variable with a new connection.

```
jumpFactory: function(event){
            var ws = this;
            ws = $.websocketSettings.factory( getEngineUrl() );
            return ws;
        },
```

Will this break the bound events on `ws`? I'm seeing some strange behaviour so trying to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: Yes, of course it will. The bindings are to the original object that ws referenced, not the variable name. In fact, the bindings will still exist, you are probably seeing events fired for the old object.

Comment: I think because you use var ws again that you might be declaring a new variable within the jumpfactory space not referencing your original ws var

Comment: @TommyBs ah good point, that could be the cause of it all. Perhaps I can attach it to `window` and reference it globally. good thinking ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't bind your events to any variable, but to its value - object referenced in it. Assigning new object to variable won't somehow automagically transfer those bindings from old object to new. Additionally those events will continue to fire as long as this object old object is referenced from somewhere.